# OpenStack - KeyStone Requires Authentication 401

Tags: python, authentication, openstack, keystone

I'm trying to list the projects (but the same thing occurs whether I try to do that, or attempt to list the users, so let's just generalise the error to any API call). Every time I do this, I get the following HTTP 401 code:

```
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 656, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 188, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/jsontools.py", line 61, in json_handler
    value = cherrypy.serving.request._json_inner_handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 34, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/var/www/frontend/controllers/api/user.py", line 63, in PUT
    print keystoneClient.projects.list()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/positional/__init__.py", line 101, in inner
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneclient/v3/projects.py", line 107, in list
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneclient/base.py", line 75, in func
    return f(*args, **new_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneclient/base.py", line 383, in list
    self.collection_key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneclient/base.py", line 124, in _list
    resp, body = self.client.get(url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/adapter.py", line 173, in get
    return self.request(url, 'GET', **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/adapter.py", line 331, in request
    resp = super(LegacyJsonAdapter, self).request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/adapter.py", line 98, in request
    return self.session.request(url, method, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/positional/__init__.py", line 101, in inner
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 387, in request
    auth_headers = self.get_auth_headers(auth)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 647, in get_auth_headers
    return auth.get_headers(self, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/plugin.py", line 84, in get_headers
    token = self.get_token(session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/base.py", line 90, in get_token
    return self.get_access(session).auth_token
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/base.py", line 136, in get_access
    self.auth_ref = self.get_auth_ref(session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/v3/base.py", line 167, in get_auth_ref
    authenticated=False, log=False, **rkwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 595, in post
    return self.request(url, 'POST', **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/positional/__init__.py", line 101, in inner
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 484, in request
    raise exceptions.from_response(resp, method, url)
Unauthorized: The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-39d02130-6f47-4cae-bc30-0b645296752e)
```

Code:

```
import cherrypy
import ldap
from keystoneauth1 import loading
from keystoneauth1 import session as session
from keystoneclient.v3 import client as client
from keystoneauth1.identity import v3
import json

    # Storing username and password in a cherrypy session
    cherrypy.session['username'] = data.get("username")
    cherrypy.session['password'] = data.get("password").replace(" ","%20")

    # Setting up KeyStone Client
    auth = v3.Password(
        auth_url = KEYSTONE_URL,
        username = cherrypy.session['username'],
        password = cherrypy.session['password'],
        user_domain_name="default",
        domain_name = "default"
    )
    sess = session.Session(auth=auth, verify='/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt')
    keystoneClient = client.Client(session=sess)

    # Getting list of projects
    print keystoneClient.projects.list()
```

This occurs whilst using a normal user's credentials. If I login using admin credentials, there is no error and the projects are listed. I would like to know:

- Why is the overall error occurring? (from what I've read, it seems like it has to reauthenticate the credentials and it doesn't like it?)
- Why is it not happening when I use admin credentials but with a 'normal' users credentials?
- How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first question, you need a project scoped token since the unscoped token doesn't have any role associated with it. You cannot do any operation with the unscoped token. Here is a way to get the project scoped token:

```
auth = v3.Password(auth_url=auth_url,
                   username=username, 
                   password=password,
                   user_domain_name="default",
                   project_name=project_name,
                   project_domain_name="default")
sess = session.Session(auth=auth, verify='/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt')
keystoneClient = client.Client(session=sess)
```

And for a normal user, you cannot get back the entire list of projects in the provider and this is why it works fine with using admin credentials but not for that of a normal user.

In order to solve it, you need to know the `user_id` of that normal user. One way is to use the admin credentials to get a keystone client and call

```
keystone.users.get(user="username")
```

Or just use the OpenStack Dashboard and go to the identity dashboard. There is a panel called `User` and you can see the `user_id` from there.

Once you have the `user_id`, you can do:

```
keystoneClient.projects.list(user=user_id)
```

HTH.